# z-order of Gnuplot functions or order in key

Tags: gnuplot

You can change the z-order of two functions plotted together by reordering the order they appear in the plot function, but this also changes the order in the key. Is there a way to reorder either the order the function appears in the key or the z-order independently of the order it appears in the plot function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get the z-order you want by simply reversing all the functions you can do

```
set key invert;
```

to reverse them in the key.